# Stumped -- Need advice with regex and preg_replace for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, regex

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this in PHP (Running 5.3.x).

I have the following string of text which I'm pulling from a txt file into a string variable:

```
garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, mor ..., garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, mor ..., more garbage here, yet more garbage
```

What I'm trying to get the string to look like and put back into the txt file is:

```
garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, more garbage here, yet more garbage
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to find each occurrence of the "..." and then remove all text behind "..." until it hits the first occurrence of "," but without any luck. Can this be done using a regex with the preg_replace function? So far, I've only managed to delete all the text between the first occurrence of "," and "..." but this is not what I want. :(

There will be no additional commas or "..." inside the "garbage here" strings...
Also "..." does not always have a trailing ",". It could just be "mor... more garbage here"

I only have PHP available for this task. Can it be done? I picked up a regex book this afternoon but so far I haven't found anything that will do exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please come up with a better title than "stumped .. need advice".

Comment: My apologizes. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following regex:

```
(^|,)[^,]*\.{3}
```

Replace matches with an empty string.

Explanation:

```
(^|,)    # match a ',' or at the start of the string
[^,]*    # match any number of characters that are not ','
\.{3}    # match three '.' characters
```

Comment: Note that this will leave a leading `,` if the first element of the string contains the `...`.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you very much sir! I had: ,(.*?)\.\.\. but that was waaaay off from what you had... I need to keep reading this regex book!

Comment: Which book you reading for regex? Checkout these two that i read on my profile [Here](http://www.coderprofile.com/coder/VBAssassin/bookshelf?category=Regular%20Expressions) . The [pocket reference](http://www.coderprofile.com/coder/VBAssassin/bookshelf/4/regular-expression-pocket-reference-regular-expressions-for-perl-ruby-php-python-c-java-and-net-pocket-reference-oreilly) one really is a MUST for anyone using regex ;)

Comment: Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl is what I picked up. I've only spent a few hours with it so far but it seems pretty good. Thank you for your suggestions, I will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your book, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

You can probably just match `...` and as many non-`,` characters (which we will represent using a negated character class) before and after it as possible (as many as, is quite simple, because repetition is greedy):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^,]*[.]{3}[^,]*/', '', $string);
```

The problem is now only the remaining commas. I would simply remove double `,,` and commas at the beginning or end of the string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^,+|,+(?=,)|,+$/', '', $string);
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/AfqObF)

Doing it all in one regex might get tricky, because you need to take care of the three cases: leading element contains `...` (remove trailing `,`), central element contains `...` (remove one of the surrounding `,`) and trailing element contains `...` (remove leading `,`).

Comment: Thank you for the online tutorial link. I will be reading this.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly specific, but this should do it:

```
$string = 'garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, mor ..., garbage here, more garbage here, more garbage, mor ..., more garbage here, yet more garbage';
echo preg_replace('/,[^,]*\.{3}/', '', $string);
```